# is is possible to make a function that when clicked changes images multiple times?

Tags: jquery, html, function, css, slider

Basically, what I need is an element that I can click, and changes from the poster image to a transition image and then to the main one. It's for a video slider, and I'm trying to cover up the loading for the videos with and image. So, when the element is clicked, the poster image switches to a gray one, that then fades to the actual video itself.

I'm using jquery and html5, and I can't seem to do it. I was hoping someone could point me to where I can find out how, or help me themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method. You pass in two arguments, the first argument is the function you want to delay, the second argument is the time in milliseconds to delay.

```
changePosterImageToATransitionImage();

window.setTimeout(  
    function() {  
        andThenToTheMainOne();  
    },  
    1000  
);
```

Comment: do you think you could point out a site that has that? I'm not sure if it's quite what I'm looking for....

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/rAhcC/ ... put your code to change to the transition image in the first function, then your code to change to the real image in the second function in the timeout method.